# Java Generic Method to Instantiate any Class with any Constructor using Reflection

Tags: java, oop, generics, reflection

As we know Java uses erasure, so any Generic class cannot do

```
T t = new T();
```

So I was trying out Java reflection to have a class with Static methods, to instantiate any Class with any Constructor. Here is the code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class GenericNewInstance {
    public static <T> T createInstance(Class<T> cObj) {
        try {
            return cObj.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println("Instantiation Exception");
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Access Exception");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static <T> T createInstanceUsingRelection(Class<T> c, Object... initArgs) {
        Constructor<T> cTor = null;
        Class<?>[] cObjs = new Class<?>[initArgs.length];
        int i = 0;

        for(Object o : initArgs) {
            cObjs[i++] = o.getClass();
        }

        try {
            cTor = c.getConstructor(cObjs);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("security exception. Cannot get Constructor");
            return null;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("NoSuchMethodException Cannot get constructor");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return cTor.newInstance(initArgs);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Argument Exception");
            return null;
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println("Instantiation Exception");
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Access Exception");
            return null;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println("Invocation Target Exception");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Example for using this.

```
Integer i = GenericNewInstance.createInstanceUsingRelection(Integer.class, "0");
```

So my questions:

1. Is this the right way to implement it? (or is it verbose?)
2. What are the typical use cases of doing this?
3. Can/Should we avoid using Reflection while using Generics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will fail at `c.getConstructor(cObjs)` since this doesn't take into account the type hierarchy. If any argument is a subtype of the constructor's declared param type, this call will not return it. You'll need quite a lot more type juggling to get it working. I advise you to take a look at the [code that already solves this problem](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L150). Perhaps you can even use that library as-is, your choice. It's the implementation code for Clojure, a JVM-based dynamic language that needs exactly this stuff. The library is available from the Maven central repo.

BTW Your exception handling is redundant. Either just declare `throws Exception` or catch any `Exception` and wrap it in a `RuntimeException`. When something fails, the original exception is the best diagnostic.

Comment: You will not only need to pass the parameter value, but the parameter type

Comment: Can you name java libraries that provide this feature?

Comment: The mentioned library is a Java library. `clojue-core.jar`.